# SQLPlus: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to update a table using SQLPlus in Oracle. My update statement is as follows, but I'm getting errors on this:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycol =
          '
CREATE OR REPLACE function stg.myfun(i_run_id number, i_rec number default 0) return number as 
begin
 insert into stg.tab (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7)
  select src.col1, src.col2, i_run_id, src.col4,''myval'', src.s1, src.s2 
    from stg.sourcetab src
   order by col1;
 return SQL%ROWCOUNT;
exception WHEN OTHERS THEN
 IF SQLCODE = -1  
  THEN
   if i_rec>15 
   then raise;
   else return stg.myfun(i_run_id, i_rec+1);
   end if;
  ELSE
   raise; 
 end if;
end;
'
where 1 = 1
and gn = 'value';
commit;
```

Errors are:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "return SQL..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "exception ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "IF SQLCODE..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0042: unknown command "THEN" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "if i_rec>1..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0042: unknown command "then raise" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "else retur..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0042: unknown command "end if" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0042: unknown command "ELSE" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0042: unknown command "raise" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0042: unknown command "end if" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0042: unknown command "end" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0042: unknown command "'" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "where 1 = ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "and gn..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Comment: It seems that SQL\*Plus can't deal with multiline string values that contain embedded `;`

Comment: You can concatenate your lines using || chr(10) ||

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be by wrapping your statement within a simple PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> begin
  2  UPDATE mytable
  3     SET mycol =
  4            '
  5  CREATE OR REPLACE function stg.myfun(i_run_id number, i_rec number default 0) return number as
  6  begin
  7   insert into stg.tab (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7)
  8    select src.col1, src.col2, i_run_id, src.col4,''myval'', src.s1, src.s2
  9      from stg.sourcetab src
 10     order by col1;
 11   return SQL%ROWCOUNT;
 12  exception WHEN OTHERS THEN
 13   IF SQLCODE = -1
 14    THEN
 15     if i_rec>15
 16     then raise;
 17     else return stg.myfun(i_run_id, i_rec+1);
 18     end if;
 19    ELSE
 20     raise;
 21   end if;
 22  end;
 23  '
 24  where 1 = 1
 25  and gn = 'value';
 26  end;
 27  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Try using the q-quote syntax, e.g. q'[ your string with quotes and ;'s  ]'

Comment: @BobC It was my first attempt, but noway

Answer (score 1):

Since you are specifically asking about SQL*Plus, you *could* change the [SQL terminator character](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG109) to something that doesn't appear in your string, or disable it altogether, either of which will stop the semicolons at the end of the lines in your string being interpreted as statement separators:

```
set sqlterminator off

UPDATE mytable
   SET mycol =
          '
CREATE OR REPLACE function stg.myfun(i_run_id number, i_rec number default 0) return number as 
begin
 insert into stg.tab (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7)
  select src.col1, src.col2, i_run_id, src.col4,''myval'', src.s1, src.s2 
    from stg.sourcetab src
   order by col1;
 return SQL%ROWCOUNT;
exception WHEN OTHERS THEN
 IF SQLCODE = -1  
  THEN
   if i_rec>15 
   then raise;
   else return stg.myfun(i_run_id, i_rec+1);
   end if;
  ELSE
   raise; 
 end if;
end;
'
where 1 = 1
and gn = 'value'
/

1 row updated.

set sqlterminator on

commit;

Commit complete.
```

Notice the update statement itself has to be terminated by a slash on a new line now (or by your specified character, if you don't just turn it off completely). And I've re-enabled it to allow semicolons to be used again for the commit.

However, that won't work in SQL Developer (at least in 4.2, which says `set sqlterminator` is obsolete) or probably other clients which are similarly confused. Wrapping in a PL/SQL block is probably a better general solution; or use bind variables, but then you'd have to assign their values carefully too.

You can also use [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) to avoid needing to escape the single quotes within the string (i.e. `''myval''`), but that doesn't stop SQL*Plus treating a trailing semicolon as a statement separator, so that would be a refinement if whichever other method you use.

Answer (score -1):

```
drop table junk;

create table junk( id number(1) not null
        , stmt varchar2(200) )
/

insert into junk values ( 1, null );
commit;

update junk
set stmt = q'[ select ename from emp where ename = 'KING'; ]'
where id = 1
;

commit
;

select * from junk
;
```

Results in

```
        ID STMT
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1  select ename from emp where ename = 'KING';
```

Comment: That doesn't help with the OP's problem - your example doesn't have a semicolon at the end of a line, which is what is tripping up the SQL\*Plus parser and making it treat it as multiple statements. Adding the alternative quoting syntax doesn't change that behaviour, unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexPoole. My example **does** have a semi-colon at the end! Look at the output !!

Comment: Look at the input though - your single  lne containing a text literal ends `...; ]'`. The OP has lines that end with just `...;`. It is those that SQL\*Plus sees as statement separators. In your example the characters after the semicolon stop that happening. Try wrapping the OP's actual multiline string in this way and you'll see, as Aleksej already said, that it still gets the same errors.

Comment: @AlexPoole. Yup, I see now.